# Magento : Enable and use table rates programmatically?

Tags: php, magento

In one of my magento projects, I have to use the Table rates shipping method in some condition. And I want to keep the Table rates disable by default. So, I want to enable the Table rates method in my custom shipping model programmatically and apply it.

What if I enable the Table rates and some how I keep it hiding through code unless it meets the certain condition.

Comment: please provide more details. 
In which condition you want to show table rates

Comment: @justcode I'm calling a soap web service to return the shipping rates. In case, if it returns nothing then the code should show the Table rates. Any idea how can I keep table rates hidden while they are enabled? They only show up when web service returns no record.

Answer (score 0):

In that case i think use jQuery

like `any_event.hide()`

```
In a loop check whether the return content
```

if the `return value is empty` then using jQuery you can hide it

Try that way